Programming languages supported for tools accepted by CTAN
Is there a list of programming languages supported for tools that can be published by CTAN? I know there is Perl? What are the others?

I think ctan accept more or less anything but texlive https://tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html recommend perl or texlua, as getting anything else to run on all the platforms they support os a pain. of course the main tools are written in  web or C/C++

pythontex sympytex sagetex latexalpha2 exists so it's pretty much "everything". Of course if you use non-standard language, expect your package to fail on many platforms or have nonstandard installation instruction i.e. not very popular.

@DavidCarlisle What exactly is texlua (compared to luatex)?

@Gaussler well texlua is a symbolic link (or copy on windows) to luatex so it's the same program but it assumes the command line file is lua rather than tex, so it's like stock lua with the luatex lua libraries preloaded, or like luatex but starting in lua mode, depending on your point of view.
